# MIPS - How do i concatenate User Input Strings and print them out after reading consecutive "\n" "\n"?

Tags: string, assembly, concatenation, mips

I have a function called saisir that needs to take in user input text and lets you enter \n 's in the input as part of the text. It returns the text that was entered by the user avec reading \n\n.

```
.data

buffer: .space 300
msg: .asciiz "You entered:\n"

.text
main: #calling the function

    jal saisir

    li $v0,10 #end the program
    syscall

saisir:
    li $v0,8 #take in input
    la $a0, buffer #address where we store buffer
    li $a1, 300
    syscall

    li $t0, 0
    lb $t0, ($a0)
    li $t1, 10 #\n caracter in ASCII

    bne $t0, $t1, saisir

    #Displays "You entered:"
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, msg
    syscall

    #Displays User's input
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, buffer
    syscall

    jr $ra #goes back
```

The code written right now overwrites every line of text entered by the user, therefore returns a string that is empty.. How to add the strings up as you would in a high level language with "+=" in MIPS?

Comment: You have two possible courses of action: single step in assembly and see if it is doing what you want and fix as needed, and, write it in C, debug it, make sure it works, then  methodically translate the C code to assembly.  Hint: the latter is easier.